# Crafting with synthweave in 4.0

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I'm a bit confused with all the changes that have been made to crafting in 4.0.

For augments i understand that it works like it did before except there are no greens anymore?

1. Buy blue schematic
2. Craft blue augment
3. RE blue augment till you get purple schematic
4. Craft purple augment

But for armoring and gear i don't really get it completely.
The best armoring schematic we can buy is a 36 one, which is barely as good as 60 end gear.
You cant RE gear or armorings from the green/blue crystals vendor.

So is the only way to get a schematic for a good armoring then from Ops?
Same for the gear, i understand that you need story mode gear to RE to get a schematic, then craft that gear and RE it to a Hard mode gear piece.

Does gear from HM FP qualify for this aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some mods can be learned from the crystal-bought gear. A friend of mine was able to learn the 220 Versatile hilt from an offhand on his Artificer.

Otherwise you are correct about augments, and yes it's Ops gear that you want in order to learn the end-game mods.  I am not sure about HM FP gear though,  maybe someone else can chime in.